# List of weigh stations in the US and their locations?

Tags: geospatial, government, transportation

I'm wondering whether there is any open data out there that comprehensively lists weigh stations in the US and their latitude/longitude. Other vehicle inspection facilities would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

**This may not be the answer you seek.**

[Weigh Station Location Information](https://www.fdot.gov/maintenance/WeighStationListing.shtm#Bunnell%20Static%20Station)

```
Weigh-in-Motion (Bi-Directional) Interstate based Weigh Stations:
Flagler / Madison / Martin / Pensacola / Punta Gorda / Seffner / Sneads / White Springs / Wildwood / Yulee

Static Station Non-Interstate based Weigh Stations:
Hilliard / Hopewell / Lake City / MacClenny / Old Town / Palatka / Palm Coast / Pensacola / Plantation Key / Yulee
```

But still, you can web scrape from the [Florida Department of TRANSPORTATION](https://www.fdot.gov/maintenance/WeighStationListing.shtm#Bunnell%20Static%20Station).

AFAIK, I haven't found a direct download of this data. It contains all the required fields

**Note:** It has only Florida Weigh station info

Comment: Thanks! That's a great suggestion. It might be feasible to do this for the mainland US since there are not that many states. It seems that there are some analogous third-party sites doing something similar.